# How to move SKSpriteNode in a curve without rotating the sprite in Swift

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, skspritenode, bezier, curve

I'm trying to move a sprite with a curve.
I got this code:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ball.position.x+200, y: ball.position.y+50), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: ball.position.x+100, y: ball.position.y+200))
    ball.run(SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, speed: 1.0))
```

I have few questions:
1 - why my sprite is rotating while moving, and if I can control this rotation?
2 - any idea why the ball is moving only small part of the way and very slow and not a smooth moving (10-20 seconds)?

Does anyone have any idea how this code works?
All the answers I found were related to older Swift version that had different method.

Comment: There is no one that can help on this? I posted this question 15 days ago and there is no answer :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I've found the solution :)

```
func beizerSprite()
   {
    // create a bezier path that defines our curve
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 16,y: 239))
    path.addCurve(to:CGPoint(x: 301, y: 239),
                  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 136, y: 373),
                  controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 178, y: 110))

    // use the beizer path in an action
    _playButton.run(SKAction.follow(path.cgPath,
                                    asOffset: false,
                                    orientToPath: true,
                                    speed: 50.0))
   }
```

This move the `SKSprite` in a curve along the screen.